# Why files can not be moved properly with 'mv' in command line

Tags: bash

I tried to move some files.

Version 1(fail):

```
FDSM_lhn@Nirvana:~/Downloads$ mv "Problem\ Set*" ../Desktop/Econ3101/
mv: rename Problem\ Set* to ../Desktop/Econ3101/Problem\ Set*: No such file or directory
```

Version 2(succeed):

```
FDSM_lhn@Nirvana:~/Downloads$ mv Problem\ Set* ../Desktop/Econ3101/
```

But Why is this happening?

Thank you!

Comment: You either escape spaces or use quotes - not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you used double quotes, you were actually trying to move a file called exactly "Problem Set*", which did not exist.

It's probably easier to understand with a simple example:

```
$> touch foo{1,2,3,4,5,*}.txt
$> ls
foo1.txt  foo2.txt  foo3.txt  foo4.txt  foo5.txt  foo*.txt
$> ls foo*.txt
foo1.txt  foo2.txt  foo3.txt  foo4.txt  foo5.txt  foo*.txt
$> ls "foo*.txt"
foo*.txt
```

Comment: Oh fine, I just want make wildcards clear of second argument so I use quote. Thank you!

Comment: To elaborate, a lot of punctuation characters (at least `*`, `?`, `(`, `)`, `{`, `}`, and `&`) have special meaning when *unquoted*. Some have special meaning even while double quoted (like `$`). [More about quotes in Bash.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)